# How to use json data instead of tsv file in d3 multi line charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

jsfiddle  link https://jsfiddle.net/8vhsLor6/

Basically I want to replace tsv file data with json object. I am getting error. Type error

```
var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
```

I have data like this

```
var data = [
{date:"1-May-12","New York":"58.13", "San Francisco":"58.13", "Austin": "43"},
{date:"30-Apr-12","New York":"53.98" , "San Francisco":"48.13", "Austin": "53"},
{date:"27-Apr-12","New York":"67.00", "San Francisco":"38.13", "Austin": "63"},
{date:"26-Apr-12","New York":"89.70", "San Francisco":"28.13", "Austin": "73"},
{date:"25-Apr-12","New York":"99.00", "San Francisco":"18.13", "Austin": "83"}
];
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/caravinden/vcuzxhdb/1/

Comment: Thanks @AravindCheekkallur it worked but some issue with Date. Going back and forth.

Comment: Please have a look on below answer..:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**d3.tsv in version 4:**

When changing the data from [Bostock's code](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) from a TSV to a JSON (or, more precisely, to a variable), you forgot something important: In the new D3 v4.x, `d3.tsv` function creates an *array property* called [`columns`](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv).

This property contains all the *headers* of the TSV file as an array. In the original code, if you `console.log(data.columns)`, you'll get this:

```
["date", "New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"];
```

So, basically, for your code to work, all I did was adding this property:

```
data.columns = ["date", "New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"];
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uz9rtcwd/

PS: You have a wrong date format. Also, you have to parse the dates in the `data` array (this step corresponds to the accessor function in the `d3.tsv`, but keep in mind that `d3.json` has no accessor function).

Comment: How to make it dynamic instead of static you have written?

Comment: What do you want to make dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

To make the multiline graph have a few steps need to be added:-

- Find out the [unique keys](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/README.md#keys) for y-axis
- [Time parsing](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#timeParse) is another important factor
- Add style for the line and path.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%e-%b-%y")

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return x(parseTime(d.date)); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });


var data = [
{date:"1-May-12","New York":"58.13", "San Francisco":"58.13", "Austin": "43"},
{date:"30-Apr-12","New York":"53.98" , "San Francisco":"48.13", "Austin": "53"},
{date:"27-Apr-12","New York":"67.00", "San Francisco":"38.13", "Austin": "63"},
{date:"26-Apr-12","New York":"89.70", "San Francisco":"28.13", "Austin": "73"},
{date:"25-Apr-12","New York":"99.00", "San Francisco":"18.13", "Austin": "83"}
];

 var keys =d3.keys(data[0]);
  var i = keys.indexOf('date')
  if(i != -1) {
    keys.splice(i, 1);
  }
  var cities = keys.map(function(d) { 
    return {
      id:d,
      values: data.map( function(e) {
        return {
          date: e.date,
          temperature: e[d]
        };
      })
  } });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parseTime(d.date); }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(d) { return d.temperature; }); }),
    d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(d) { return d.temperature; }); })
  ]);

  z.domain(cities.map(function(c) { return c.id; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .text("Temperature, ºF");

  var city = g.selectAll(".city")
    .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {  return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d.id); });

  city.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) { return {id: d.id, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {  return "translate(" + x(parseTime(d.value.date)) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}


.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
```

`var keys =d3.keys(data[0]);
  var i = keys.indexOf('date')
  if(i != -1) {
    keys.splice(i, 1);
  }
  var cities = keys.map(function(d) { 
    return {
      id:d,
      values: data.map( function(e) {
        return {
          date: e.date,
          temperature: e[d]
        };
      })
  } });`

Comment: May i know the problem of this answer really?