# How to map json data containing an array of datas and one date?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, key

I want to create a graph who look like this one [How to use json data instead of tsv file in d3 multi line charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717041/how-to-use-json-data-instead-of-tsv-file-in-d3-multi-line-charts)

For this, I use JSON data but there is something I don't understand in the mapping of my datas

```
    {
"Session_test": [{
    "datas_lines": [{
            "datas_line": [],
            "log_time": "No data"
        },
        {
            "datas_line": [],
            "log_time": "No data"
        },
        {
            "datas_line": [],
            "log_time": "No data"
        },
        {
            "datas_line": [
                "157",
                "158",
                "157",
                "157",
                "157",
                "158",
                "159",
                "161",
                "160",
                "160",
                "159",
                "158",
                "159",
                "160",
                "160",
                "160",
                "160",
                "161",
                "160",
                "161",
                "159",
                "161",
                "161",
                "158",
                "161",
                "159",
                "160",
                "157"
            ],
            "log_time": "5/18/2017 4:32:14 PM"
        },
        {
            "datas_line": [
                "154",
                "156",
                "155",
                "155",
                "155",
                "156",
                "158",
                "159",
                "158",
                "157",
                "157",
                "156",
                "157",
                "158",
                "159",
                "158",
                "158",
                "159",
                "159",
                "159",
                "158",
                "159",
                "159",
                "156",
                "159",
                "157",
                "158",
                "156"
            ],
            "log_time": "5/18/2017 4:34:14 PM"
        },
        {
            "datas_line": [
                "154",
                "156",
                "155",
                "155",
                "155",
                "156",
                "158",
                "159",
                "158",
                "157",
                "157",
                "156",
                "157",
                "158",
                "159",
                "158",
                "158",
                "159",
                "159",
                "159",
                "158",
                "159",
                "159",
                "156",
                "159",
                "157",
                "158",
                "156"
            ],
            "log_time": "5/18/2017 4:34:14 PM"
        }
    ]
}]
}
```

So, I have an array of objet and each object contain a log_time (date) and an array of number.

I need to get this format to exploit them :

```
var data = [
{log_time:"5/18/2017 4:32:14 PM","0":"157", "1":"158", "2": "157", etc...},
{log_time:"5/18/2017 4:32:14 PM","0":"154" , "1":"156", "2": "155", etc...}
];
```

How can I produce something similar ?

My actual code :

```
var dateKey = d3.keys(data[0]);
var i = keys.indexOf('log_time')
if(i != -1) {
    keys.splice(i, 1);
}
var temp_list = keys.map(function(d) { 
    return {
      id:d,
      values: data.map( function(e) {
        return {
          date: e.log_time,
          temperature: e[d]
        };
      })
  } });
  console.log(temp_list);
```

I'm currently re-used the code from this post : [How to use json data instead of tsv file in d3 multi line charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717041/how-to-use-json-data-instead-of-tsv-file-in-d3-multi-line-charts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
let responses = [];


// your data
let data = Session_test[0].datas_lines;

data.forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.log_time !== "No data") {
        let iterator = 0;
        let final = {};
        obj.datas_line.forEach(d => {
        final[iterator.toString()] = d;
        iterator++;
        });
        final.log_time = obj.log_time;
        responses.push(final);

    }
});
```

explanation: You just need to check whether log_time properties contain data or not. If it does, just run a for loop over the values and keep adding it into an object.Once the object is complete, push it to an array.

Comment: It worked perfectly dude ! That was exactly what I wanted. I didn't know that we could do like that, I thought I had to use a map.

Comment: glad i could be of help.

Comment: It seem there is a little error because the key of numbers are not working due to the fact iterator.toString(). Check with console.log(final) and the key is not a string.

Comment: Also, I don't get it because it seem there is an error on this because at the end everything is ok and I get an error "Value translated (Nan,450) unexpected during the analysis of transform attribute

Comment: For your first question, objects can only have string keys, not numbers. I just checked, even if you dont apply the toString operator, it will still convert the number to a string before using it as a key. However, the problem with number keys is that you cant use the . (dot) operator to access the object properties. You will need to access the properties by using [] e.g. responses[0]["0"]. To check the type of the keys, try Object.keys(responses[0]) and you will see that all the keys are returned as string.

Comment: For your second question, i dont understand what's the error. can you please provide a bit more detail?