# Why I get the error value translated(Nan, 450) unexpected during analysis of transform attributes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm developing a graph like this one [How to use json data instead of tsv file in d3 multi line charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717041/how-to-use-json-data-instead-of-tsv-file-in-d3-multi-line-charts)

I use data from a JSON file.
I checked and everything seem ok but I get an error that I don't understand:
`value translation (Nan, 450) unexpected during analysis of transform attributes`
This error appear each time I want draw a point.

My current code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
  .axis--x path {
    display: none;
  }

  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = { top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p");

  var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  var line = d3
    .line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function (d) {
      return x(parseTime(d.date));
    })
    .y(function (d) {
      return y(d.temperature);
    });

  d3.json("testSerialisation_v4.ujson", function (error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var data = data["Session_test"][0]["datas_lines"];

    let responses = [];

    data.forEach((obj) => {
      if (obj.log_time !== "No data") {
        let iterator = 0;
        let final = {};
        obj.datas_line.forEach((d) => {
          final[iterator.toString()] = d;
          iterator++;
        });
        console.log("ici");
        final.log_time = obj.log_time;
        responses.push(final);
      }
    });

    var dateKey = d3.keys(responses[0]);
    var i = dateKey.indexOf("log_time");
    if (i != -1) {
      dateKey.splice(i, 1);
    }
    var temp_list = dateKey.map(function (d) {
      return {
        id: d,
        values: responses.map(function (e) {
          return {
            date: e.log_time,
            temperature: e[d],
          };
        }),
      };
    });

    x.domain(
      d3.extent(responses, function (d) {
        return parseTime(d.date);
      })
    );
    y.domain([
      d3.min(temp_list, function (c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function (d) {
          return d.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(temp_list, function (c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function (d) {
          return d.temperature;
        });
      }),
    ]);

    z.domain(
      temp_list.map(function (c) {
        return c.id;
      })
    );

    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .text("Temperature, ยบF");

    var city = g
      .selectAll(".city")
      .data(temp_list)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    city
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function (d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function (d) {
        return z(d.id);
      });

    city
      .append("text")
      .datum(function (d) {
        return { id: d.id, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1] };
      })
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return (
          "translate(" +
          x(parseTime(d.value.date)) +
          "," +
          y(d.value.temperature) +
          ")"
        );
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.id;
      });
    console.log;
  });
</script>
```

My datas looks like this :

```json
{
  "Session_test": [
    {
      "datas_lines": [
        {
          "datas_line": [],
          "log_time": "No data"
        },
        {
          "datas_line": [],
          "log_time": "No data"
        },
        {
          "datas_line": [],
          "log_time": "No data"
        },
        {
          "datas_line": [
            "157",
            "158",
            "157",
            "157",
            "157",
            "158",
            "159",
            "161",
            "160",
            "160",
            "159",
            "158",
            "159",
            "160",
            "160",
            "160",
            "160",
            "161",
            "160",
            "161",
            "159",
            "161",
            "161",
            "158",
            "161",
            "159",
            "160",
            "157"
          ],
          "log_time": "5/18/2017 4:32:14 PM"
        },
        {
          "datas_line": [
            "154",
            "156",
            "155",
            "155",
            "155",
            "156",
            "158",
            "159",
            "158",
            "157",
            "157",
            "156",
            "157",
            "158",
            "159",
            "158",
            "158",
            "159",
            "159",
            "159",
            "158",
            "159",
            "159",
            "156",
            "159",
            "157",
            "158",
            "156"
          ],
          "log_time": "5/18/2017 4:34:14 PM"
        },
        {
          "datas_line": [
            "154",
            "156",
            "155",
            "155",
            "155",
            "156",
            "158",
            "159",
            "158",
            "157",
            "157",
            "156",
            "157",
            "158",
            "159",
            "158",
            "158",
            "159",
            "159",
            "159",
            "158",
            "159",
            "159",
            "156",
            "159",
            "157",
            "158",
            "156"
          ],
          "log_time": "5/18/2017 4:34:14 PM"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So did you debug all the values you are outputting and figure out what part is crapping out? console.log() is your friend.

Comment: Yes @epascarello , I already did that and eveything look fine on this side

Comment: Did you debug what one of all the calls is doing it? You need to narrow it down for us since we can not run it....

Comment: Sorry @epascarello post edited. So it seem the error come from parseTime(d.value.date) -> is NaN . How can i resolve it ?

Comment: Ok, I solve it It was a problem from the domain